# Matrix question MCQ

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I don't even know how to start with this type of question. Please help.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a weird question. The author obviously knows something we don't. But since it is multiple choice, one can eliminate the choices: put $a=b=0$ and $c=1$. Then the four choices evaluate to $x^4$, $x^4$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ respectively. But the determinant at the top is $1$. Under $x^3=1$, the match is (D; for the complex roots of $1$, the other two would not match 1.